# Degree of the splitting field of $x^{p^2} -2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, for prime p.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I've already shown that the degree of the splitting field of $x^p-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $p(p-1)$ as follows:

$x^p-2$ has roots $\sqrt[p]{2}\omega_{k}$ for $k=0,1,...,p-1$, where the $\omega_{k}$ are the $p^{th}$ roots of unity.

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = p$ since $x^p-2$ is irreducible,

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega_{k}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})] = p-1$, since $\omega_{k}$ satisfies $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x+1$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by substituting y+1 = x and using Eisenstein. Since gcd$(p, p-1)=1$ it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$.

$\implies[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega_{k}):\mathbb{Q}] = p(p-1)$.

Now onto $x^{p^2} -2$, which has roots $\sqrt[p^2]{2}\omega_{r}$ for $r=0,1,...,p^2-1$.

Since $x^{p^2} -2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} \implies [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p^2]{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = p^2$.

Next, I need to find the degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p^2]{2}, \omega_{r}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p^2]{2})]$.

Using the same method as above, $\omega_{r}$ satisfies $x^{p^2-1}+x^{p^2-2}+...+x+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. However in this case, gcd$(p^2, p^2-1)$ need not be 1.

So is this polynomial reducible? How can I find $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p^2]{2}, \omega_{r}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p^2]{2})]$?

Comment: Wait, a primitive $p^2$-th root of unity has minimal polynomial of degree $\varphi(p^2) = p(p-1)$.

Comment: The primitive root of order $p^2$, say $\omega=e^{2\pi i/p^2},$ is a root of
$$\frac{x^{p^2}-1}{x^p-1}=x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+\cdots+x^p+1.$$ That is known to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: So is it going to be the case that the degree of the splitting field will be $p^2 . p . (p-1)$?

Comment: That's correct, Lewy.

Answer (score 3):

An argument that depends on a bit of algebraic number theory, so may not be very useful to you.

The prime ideal $(2)$ is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\root {p^2}\of 2)/\mathbb{Q}$, but it is unramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore the two extension fields are linearly disjoint, and we get that
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \root {p^2}\of 2):\mathbb{Q}]=
[\mathbb{Q}(\root {p^2}\of 2):\mathbb{Q}]\cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}].
$$
Therefore
$$
\Phi_{p^2}(x)=x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+\cdots+x^{2p}+x^p+1
$$
remains irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\root {p^2}\of 2)$.

Comment: This argument needs the extra assumption $p>2$.